# File upload works with <10Kb files only

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to upload files to a server using jQuery File Upload. For now I'm using the Demo page inside the library.

When I upload a PNG file under 10 Kb it works as intended. However if the file is over 10 Kb, I get an `[Error] Unknown error` and the browser console shows `POST /server/php/ 403` error.

This is what I have tried so far:

- chmod -R 0777 on fileupload folder
- add `client_max_body_size 100M;` to nginx.conf file in http section
- set `upload_max_filesize = 100M` in php.ini
- set `post_max_size = 100M` in php.ini

Then restart php-fpm and nginx. Did I miss something?

Edit: I compared 2 requests headers. One from the upload of a 9.33KB image and the other one from an 11.07KB image. The first request was successful, `status code:200`, the second was denied, `status code:403`. The only difference in the 2 requests headers is the `content-length`. 9525 for the first one and 11262 for the second one.

Edit 2: I don't know if it's relevant but, the Nginx server I'm working on is hosted on an AWS EC2 instance and I just read somewhere that this might be the cause. However I am not the owner of the AWS instance and I have no access to its configuration (if a configuration is possible?).

Comment: How much greater than 5K when the error happens, just a bit bigger or a LOT BIGGER

Comment: I removed reference to jQuery in the question, as if it works for small files it's not an issue with the JS

Comment: _Small Point, probably not relevant to this issue BUT_ files are uploaded as part of the POST therefore `post_max_size` should definitely be Greater than `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: @RiggsFolly the error happen from 10 KB I think. I have png of 11 KB that trow the error. I can set post_max_size to 100M or 150M. I'm willing to try anything ;)

Comment: Well if you are only sending one 11KB file then your current setting are not going to be the issues

Comment: 1) what do your logs say 2) did you try a plain HTTP upload without using jquery

Comment: @symcbean sorry, not familiar with this. Where can I see my logs ? No I didn't try to upload without jquery. I will try right now.

Comment: Where your logs are often depends upon your OS, but that has been answered many times so you can probably get that answer from a google

Comment: Okay, I'll find it. In the meantime I set up the upload with a simple html file and a php file to process the upload. I get the same result, with a 5 KB image, it works while with the 11 KB image, I get the 403 Forbidden error page. :(

Comment: I found in the access.log the lines where I tried to upload but in the error.log there is nothing. No error is written there.

Comment: Then you **must** fix your error reporting.

Comment: The error report is fine, I've seen previous errors. you misunderstood me, the file is not empty but no errors are reported at the times I tried to upload.

Comment: There must be something else in play here. A file upload that runs into any of the limits, would either cause a 500 error, or give you error information inside the $_FILES array at runtime. You would not automatically get a 403 Forbidden instead - it must be something else, forcing that. If you get the same problem with just a normal form and a PHP script to receive the upload, then it’s not a problem of the jQuery File Upload plugin either.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the problem does not come from the jQuery File Upload plugin. I tried with a simple html+php page I copied from there https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp and the result is the same.
I'm thinking about the nginx configuration itself but I can't find any information about this problem. This is the first time I use Nginx and I've never had this kind of problem with Apache. It's very frustrating...

Comment: The subject is resolved, thank you all for your help. The owner of the server had installed a WebApplicationFirewall that blocked all unusual request like "big" post...